# non-uniform scale and vector mapping in blender uv unwrapping

Tags: vector-mapping

Hi i am trying to apply some bump maps and normal maps to a floor in my scene but when i uv unwrap it blender warns of non-uniform scale and i think because of that Vector Mapping is resulting in some wired shape

Comment: Apply your transformations: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data